# ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry returns false for attached object

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

TryGetObjectStateEntry returns false but when i try to attach the entity i get 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.'

The entity key is of type Guid.

How is this possible?

**Edit:** i am attaching 2 entities with different key. the error occurs always on the second entity of this type that i attach. if i swap them the error is still on the 2nd one.

```
    public bool IsAttached<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        ObjectStateEntry entry = null;

        ObjectContext objCtx = GetObjectContext();

        bool isKeyAttached = false;

        EntityContainer container = objCtx.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objCtx.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
        EntitySetBase entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets.Where(item => item.ElementType.Name.Equals(typeof(T).Name)).FirstOrDefault();
        System.Data.EntityKey key = objCtx.CreateEntityKey(entitySet.Name, obj);

        if (objCtx.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(key, out entry))
        {
            isKeyAttached = entry.State != System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
        }

        return isKeyAttached;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur if the entities you attach have navigation properties refering to other entities. Example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The following code will throw an exception:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var parent = new Parent { Id = 1 };
    var child1 = new Child { Id = 1 };
    parent.Child = child1;

    var child2 = new Child { Id = 1 };  // same key

    context.Children.Attach(child2);    // child with key = 1 is attached now

    var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

    ObjectStateEntry entry;
    bool isAttached = objContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(
        new EntityKey("MyDbContext.Parents", "Id", parent.Id), out entry);
    // isAttached will be false because a Parent with Id = 1 is not attached
    if (!isAttached)
    {
        // we assume now that we could attach the parent safely
        context.Parents.Attach(parent);

        // Assumption is wrong -> Exception, because Attach attaches the whole
        // object graph, so it tries also to attach child1 together with parent
        // But child1 has the same key as child2 which is already attached
    }
}
```

So, the point is that `TryGetObjectStateEntry` only checks the state of the base entity and doesn't consider any navigation properties. `Attach` on the other hand does not only attach the base entity but also the children which are not yet attached, leading to the exception.

Comment: i put a breakpoint on the Equals function of the entity and i saw it's always comparing with the key of the first entity attached. so when i attach the 2nd entity the Equals function still gets hit with the first entity i already attached not the 2ndone i'm attaching in that moment.

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't understand what you want to say in your comment. The question is: When you attach your 2 entities with different key, do these entities have any children which have the same key? In this case the error would occur.

Comment: No, they're GUIDs, so they're all unique. It's almost asif it's looking at the wrong entity. When i call Attach the framework checks to see if the entity isnt already attached using the equals function on the object, right. when i attach the 2nd entity the equals functions are always called with the 1nd entity's key, not the 2nd.

Comment: @Jeroen: You could check the content of the context in the debugger before you attach the second entity by using `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()`. Each element `entry` in this collection has an `Entity` property which shows the entities and their values which are in the context. So, you can see if there is already a child with the same key you want to attach. The exception is pretty clear, there *must* be such a duplicate key, otherwise EF would have a very serious bug.

Comment: This is a good analysis of the underlying issue; is there a solution to the problem of attaching entities with shared navigation properties? This seems like it would be an exceedingly common scenario.

Comment: @bwerks: I'm not aware of an easy solution. In order to avoid this exception the detached object graph must contain only objects that are unique per key value. If there are two objects with the same key one must be replaced by the other before the graph gets attached. Nothing is built-in into EF to deal with that, it will be hand-written code like traversing the graph, maintain a (entity key, entity object)-dictionary, lookup, add and replace... or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Entity Framework 6.4.4 but the problem was that I misunderstood the syntax for `EntityKey`'s `qualifiedEntitySetName` constructor parameter.

In my example, I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders (
    TenantId int NOT NULL,
    OrderId  int NOT NULL,
    etc

    CONSTRAINT PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY ( TenantId, OrderId )
)
```

The `qualifiedEntitySetName` argument must consist of two labels separated by a dot, e.g. `Foo.Bar` - I thought the name would be the fully-qualified database object name (i.e. I thought it would be `dbo.Orders`), but the first part must actually be the `DbContext` name.

This was my incorrect code:

```
Boolean TryGetOrderFromContext( this ContosoDbContext db, Int32 tenantId, Int32 orderId, out Order order )
{
    EntityKey orderKey;
    {
        KeyValuePair<String,Object>[] orderKeyValues = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<String,Object>( "TenantId", tenantId ),
            new KeyValuePair<String,Object>( "OrderId" , orderId  )
        };

        orderKey = new EntityKey( qualifiedEntitySetName: "dbo.Orders", entityKeyValues: orderKeyValues )
    }
    
    ObjectContext      objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
    ObjectStateManager objMgr = db.ObjectStateManager;
    
    if( osm.TryGetObjectStateEntry( orderKey, out ObjectStateEntry se ) )
    {
        order = se.Entity;
        if( order is null ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "se.Entity is null." );
        return true;
    }

    order = default;
    return false;
}
```

As my `DbContext` is named `ContosoDbContext` the `EntityKey` constructor and the rest of the code should have been like this:

```
Boolean TryGetOrderFromContext( this ContosoDbContext db, Int32 tenantId, Int32 orderId, out Order order )
{
    EntityKey orderKey;
    {
        KeyValuePair<String,Object>[] orderKeyValues = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<String,Object>( "TenantId", tenantId ),
            new KeyValuePair<String,Object>( "OrderId" , orderId  )
        };

        orderKey = new EntityKey( qualifiedEntitySetName: "ContosoDbContext.Orders", entityKeyValues: orderKeyValues )
    }
    
    // etc
}
```

...and now `TryGetObjectStateEntry` correctly returns `true`!

Comment: So you only confirm that OP's code is correct. You don't answer the question. Of course there can be countless way to make errors here, no need to post them IMO.

Comment: @GertArnold Right, I posted my answer because I had **the same symptoms** but a different cause and solution. That doesn't invalidate my answer. The OP wasn't using the same `EntityKey` constructor I was.

Comment: Of course it does. Sorry, but it's really not interesting for everyone that you spotted an error in your code. OP already showed how to do this right, and even better, because generically.

Comment: @GertArnold What I'm saying is that _other people might have made the same mistake I did_. Seemingly the majority of question posts on SO are created by people not understanding how to use a library or API, that doesn't mean they're invalid either. (SO rules only close **errors caused by typos**, not improper API usage). EF's documentation is poor in comparison to the rest of the .NET ecosystem (e.g. the documentation for `EntityKey`'s constructor does not describe how `qualifiedEntitySetName` should be set, so I feel my answer has value.