# EF4 can’t add an object to the context even though I’m convinced it is not attached

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, poco, objectcontext

I can’t add an object to the ObjectContext even though I’m convinced it is not attached and it is not associated with a different context

I am using EF 4 with POCO objects.

If I try

```
_currentContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityIn)
```

Then I get the error

```
The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.OrderItem_7D361CB49D75AA90681B4BA3F924139ECB0FC1426E38E90C7B884A4E9CD777DF'.
```

Fair enough it’s not there. So if I try to attach it

```
_currentContext.AttachTo("OrderItems", entityIn)
```

Then I get

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

How can I be getting both errors. Don’t they contradict?? How can I attach it to the context?

**Edit**

There is only one context throughout the app. The pattern is

1. All calls through repository objects.
2. The objects get their objectcontext from a factory class.
3. This factory class either creates a context or gets the context from the request object thus guaranteeing only one context is used for the page lifecycle

At any point if you take two instantiations of the context object the hash code for each one is the same.

Comment: Does your OrderItem you try to attach reference an Order (or another entity) and an Order with the same key is already attached? Then it could be a problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938728/objectstatemanager-trygetobjectstateentry-returns-false-for-attached-object/7938909#7938909

Comment: Good guess with Order @Slauma. Have you seen my schema (joke). That's probably it thanks. But given this is the case how can I attach order items if the underlying order is already attached and will cause this problem. I'm I missing something obvious?

Comment: It would not be a problem if the attached Order is the same object as the Order referenced by the OrderItem. But this error indicates that you have an Order (hash=x, key=1) which is attached and another Order object with same key (hash=y, key=1). If you have this you basically must replace the detached Order (referenced by the OrderItem) by the attached Order OR set the reference from the OrderItem to the Order to `null` before you attach. My guess could also be wrong, I'm not sure if this error about multiple instances of `IEntityChangeTracker` has really the same reason as my linked answer.

Comment: thanks again for this. It errors when I set any populated navigation property to null. I'll keep investigating thanks

Comment: Maybe you are not allowing your foreign keys to be nullable. That said, instead of setting objects to your navigation properties, set the corresponding ID fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object, `entityIn` probably has a reference to an object which is in another context.

However, the *real* problem here is that you have multiple contexts in scope *at all.* It is **hard** to do that right. In a web application, you should have one context per request, period.

Comment: I use Ninject to serve up a single context per request to all my repositories. Works like a charm. Any IoC container should do the job, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Craig Stuntz. In the app there is only one context associated with the request object as you suggest. I have edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: If you get the "by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" error, then you **do** have multiple contexts involved, *period.* That error does not mean anything else; there is only one thing which causes it. It's just that the object which is in another context is not `entityIn`; it's some object that `entityIn` is associated with.

Comment: OK i admit you're right @Craig Stuntz though it's taken me a long time to realise it. Although the context is served through a factory method and there is only ever one context per request the problem was that I had an entity saved into session and it was this that was giving this error. Lesson learned from this is not to save entities into session as they cause the code to blow up like this